# Data preprocessing using Python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, data-preprocessing

I have a data frame wherein there are 2 streams of time-series values, and along with that, there is an attribute assigned to a few of the values therein.

| VAL1 | VAL2 | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1221 | 1221 | O |  |
| 1121 | 1228 | O |  |
| 1323 | 1425 | O |  |
| 1522 | 1222 |  | X |
| 1824 | 1128 |  |  |
| 1286 | 1221 | O |  |
| 1829 | 1245 |  |  |
| 1111 | 1421 |  | X |
| 1123 | 1622 |  | X |
| 1276 | 1282 | O |  |
| 1262 | 1542 |  | X |
| 1423 | 1228 | O |  |

I want an output where the attributes are alternating and are not repeated sequentially.
To do the same I wanted my logic to select the highest value amongst the first 3 rows from column val1 (i.e. 1323) [Similarly lowest value for ATT2 from val2]

I tried to split the data frame into various chunks where attribute 1 or 2 is repeated sequentially and then find the largest value amongst the same, but it's not giving the desired result.

Eventually, I want the data frame to look something like this.

| VAL1 | VAL2 | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1323 | 1425 | O |  |
| 1522 | 1222 |  | X |
| 1286 | 1221 | O |  |
| 1111 | 1421 |  | X |
| 1276 | 1282 | O |  |
| 1262 | 1542 |  | X |
| 1423 | 1228 | O |  |

Also, wish to create a list out of it as follows.
list = [1323, 1222, 1286, 1421, 1276, 1542, 1423]

Answer (score 0):

To alternate the rows, you do the following:

```
# create a df with only ATT1 in the right order.
df1 = df[~df['ATT1'].isna()].sort_values(by='VAL1', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

# do the same but then with ATT2 and reversed order. 
df2 = df[~df['ATT2'].isna()].sort_values(by='VAL2', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)

# On the second one, create an index that will fit neatly with the df1 index.
df2.index = df2.index + 0.5

# concat the df's and sort by index.
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(final_df)
```

The result is this:

```
   VAL1  VAL2 ATT1 ATT2
0  1423  1228    O  NaN
1  1522  1222  NaN    X
2  1323  1425    O  NaN
3  1111  1421  NaN    X
4  1286  1221    O  NaN
5  1262  1542  NaN    X
6  1276  1282    O  NaN
7  1123  1622  NaN    X
8  1221  1221    O  NaN
9  1121  1228    O  NaN
```

As to your final question; how to get a list of values alternating from two columns, we can bank on the previous split:

```
for_list = pd.concat([df1[['VAL1']], df2[['VAL2']].rename(columns={'VAL2': 'VAL1'})]).sort_index()
l = for_list['VAL1'].to_list()
print(l)
```

This will result in `[1423, 1222, 1323, 1421, 1286, 1542, 1276, 1622, 1221, 1121]`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- The *empty* values in the columns `ATT1` and `ATT2` of `df` are `NaN`, i.e. `NaN`, `None`, etc. If the those values are actually the empty string `""` then replace `.isna()` in the following with `.eq("")`.
- There's no row where both columns `ATT1` and `ATT2` are filled.

You could try the following:

```py
m = df["ATT1"].isna()
idx_O = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())["VAL1"].idxmax().to_list()
m = df["ATT2"].isna()
idx_X = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())["VAL2"].idxmin().to_list()
res = df.loc[sorted(idx_O + idx_X)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

- Build a mask `m` where `ATT1`/`ATT2` is `NaN`. Then pick the indices where `VAL1`/`VAL2` is maximal/minimal for the groups of "connected" values by using `.idxmax`/`.idxmin`
- Then select the corresponding parts of `df` after sorting the selected indices.

Result for the sample:

```
   VAL1  VAL2 ATT1 ATT2
0  1323  1425    O  NaN
1  1522  1222  NaN    X
2  1286  1221    O  NaN
3  1111  1421  NaN    X
4  1276  1282    O  NaN
5  1262  1542  NaN    X
6  1423  1228    O  NaN
```

For the second part you could try:

```py
values = res["VAL1"].where(res["ATT1"].notna(), res["VAL2"]).to_list()
```

Result for the sample:

```
[1323, 1222, 1286, 1421, 1276, 1542, 1423]
```

Comment: There is a possibility that ATT1 or ATT2 does not alternate and keeps repeating line by line. In that case I would prefer to take the largest value in those repetitions for ATT1 and smallest value for ATT2. Any inputs on that?

Comment: @mshah I don't understand: could you edit an example into your question?