# Select largest/smallest value from data frame line by line or chunk wise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-preprocessing

We have the following data frame.

| Val1 | Val2 | H | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 244.2 | 233.05 | H | None |
| 261.2 | 252.8 | H | None |
| 242.35 | 235.8 | H | None |
| 251.1 | 244.55 | H | None |
| 244.5 | 239.55 | None | L |
| 271.25 | 262.55 | H | None |
| 274 | 270.45 | H | None |
| 245.05 | 236.65 | None | L |
| 243.35 | 237.55 | None | L |
| 255.7 | 251.55 | H | None |
| 248.8 | 243.2 | None | L |
| 283.75 | 272.15 | H | None |
| 269.45 | 262.7 | None | L |
| 260.6 | 254.6 | H | None |
| 285 | 275 | None | L |
| 272.5 | 265.35 | None | L |
| 267 | 254.85 | None | L |
| 256.65 | 253.5 | None | L |
| 268 | 257.75 | H | None |
| 272.1 | 266.75 | H | None |
| 281.45 | 272.85 | None | L |
| 288.75 | 282.05 | H | None |
| 268.75 | 264.5 | None | L |
| 283 | 275.75 | None | L |
| 285.95 | 278.15 | H | None |
| 271.35 | 265.2 | None | L |
| 308.15 | 300 | H | None |
| 312.85 | 304.7 | H | None |
| 311.55 | 302.2 | None | L |
| 327.4 | 318.65 | H | None |
| 327 | 319.5 | H | None |
| 318.7 | 313.9 | None | L |
| 293.1 | 283.45 | None | L |
| 306 | 301.5 | H | None |
| 303.9 | 296.2 | None | L |
| 293.4 | 261.55 | None | L |
| 302.8 | 298.1 | H | None |
| 293.7 | 289.05 | None | L |
| 267.95 | 264.05 | None | L |
| 276.55 | 273.2 | H | None |
| 268.15 | 255 | None | L |
| 314 | 303.9 | None | L |
| 324.2 | 311.05 | H | None |
| 332.35 | 323.8 | H | None |
| 312.35 | 306.3 | H | None |
| 308.4 | 300.2 | None | L |
| 312.5 | 308.55 | None | L |
| 365.7 | 355.6 | H | None |
| 334 | 318.8 | H | None |
| 319.3 | 313.95 | None | L |
| 327.8 | 323.15 | H | None |

I want a data frame which alternates between H and L values. However as seen in the frame, few H values have formed clusters in the following time series data. I want to select the highest value amongst the cluster for H fields and lowest value amongst the cluster for L fields.

The output should look as follows.

| Val1 | Val2 | H | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 261.2 | 252.8 | H | None |
| 244.5 | 239.55 | None | L |
| 274 | 270.45 | H | None |
| 245.05 | 236.65 | None | L |
| 255.7 | 251.55 | H | None |
| 248.8 | 243.2 | None | L |
| 283.75 | 272.15 | H | None |
| 269.45 | 262.7 | None | L |
| 260.6 | 254.6 | H | None |
| 256.65 | 253.5 | None | L |
| 272.1 | 266.75 | H | None |
| 281.45 | 272.85 | None | L |
| 288.75 | 282.05 | H | None |
| 268.75 | 264.5 | None | L |
| 285.95 | 278.15 | H | None |
| 271.35 | 265.2 | None | L |
| 312.85 | 304.7 | H | None |
| 311.55 | 302.2 | None | L |
| 327.4 | 318.65 | H | None |
| 293.1 | 283.45 | None | L |
| 306 | 301.5 | H | None |
| 293.4 | 261.55 | None | L |
| 302.8 | 298.1 | H | None |
| 267.95 | 264.05 | None | L |
| 276.55 | 273.2 | H | None |
| 268.15 | 255 | None | L |
| 332.35 | 323.8 | H | None |
| 308.4 | 300.2 | None | L |
| 365.7 | 355.6 | H | None |
| 319.3 | 313.95 | None | L |
| 327.8 | 323.15 | H | None |

I tried a variety of functions from pandas but cannot get such desired result.

Comment: How is that not solved by my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75494655/14311263) to your last question?

Comment: Why the 4th line of your output has val1=245.05? There is a smaller one in the same group. Sure, then it is val2 that is not the smallest. But you haven't said how to select. What do you call "smallest" or "biggest"? val1? val2? val1 then val2? val1+val2? val1×val2? What is the criterion

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# ensure real None/NaN
df = df.replace('None', None)

# identify null values
m1 = df['H'].isna()
m2 = df['L'].isna()

# make groups of consecutive non-null
# get rows with max Val1 per group of H
# and rows with min Val1 per group of L
idx = (set(df['Val1'].groupby(m1.cumsum()[~m1]).idxmax())
      |set(df['Val1'].groupby(m2.cumsum()[~m2]).idxmin())
      )

# index those rows
out = df.loc[sorted(idx)]
```

Output:

```
      Val1    Val2     H     L
1   261.20  252.80     H  None
4   244.50  239.55  None     L
6   274.00  270.45     H  None
8   243.35  237.55  None     L
9   255.70  251.55     H  None
10  248.80  243.20  None     L
11  283.75  272.15     H  None
12  269.45  262.70  None     L
13  260.60  254.60     H  None
17  256.65  253.50  None     L
19  272.10  266.75     H  None
20  281.45  272.85  None     L
21  288.75  282.05     H  None
22  268.75  264.50  None     L
24  285.95  278.15     H  None
25  271.35  265.20  None     L
27  312.85  304.70     H  None
28  311.55  302.20  None     L
29  327.40  318.65     H  None
32  293.10  283.45  None     L
33  306.00  301.50     H  None
35  293.40  261.55  None     L
36  302.80  298.10     H  None
38  267.95  264.05  None     L
39  276.55  273.20     H  None
40  268.15  255.00  None     L
43  332.35  323.80     H  None
45  308.40  300.20  None     L
47  365.70  355.60     H  None
49  319.30  313.95  None     L
50  327.80  323.15     H  None
```